# opengles 2.0 not compiling fragment shader code

Tags: android, opengl-es, compilation, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I have been working on an app but I am getting to some errors I cant explain.
these errors only appear on my oneplus 3 but not using the google nexus 6p genymotion emulator.

I have searched for hours but i couldn't find an awnser.

this is my compilation code:

```
public static int loadShader(int shaderType, String source){
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
    if (shader != 0) {
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        int[] compiled = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader,GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled,0);   
        if (compiled[0] == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader " + shaderType + ":");
            Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
            shader = 0;
        }
    }
    return shader;
}
```

my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 vColor;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

this is the error:

```
E/MyGLRenderer: Could not compile shader 35632:
E/MyGLRenderer: ERROR: 0:1: 'in' : Syntax error:  syntax error
                INTERNAL ERROR: no main() function!
                ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by first trying it on my old galaxy ace 2, fixed all the errors on that device and it all worked again.
thing I changed:

- added #verion 100%n
- after reading shader file I put the 1 line string into String.Format(string) so the %n would be converted to a newline(compiler would complain about unknow characters behind version number)